# FastReports - programatically set text in a text object field

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, fastreport

I am trying to pass the content of AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0] to a Memo 4 of the frxreport1. The AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0] is date type (psDate). So before I open the report I would like the Memo to display my statusbar date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out  this by myself :

```
procedure TForm1.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Memo: TfrxMemoView;
  Component: TfrxComponent;
  begin
Component := frxReport1.FindObject('Memo4');
  if Component is TfrxMemoView then
  begin
    Memo := Component as TfrxMemoView;
    Memo.Text := AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text;
    frxReport1.ShowReport;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text of a fastreport memo from code like this:

```
procedure SetMemo(aReport: TfrxReport; aMemoName: string; aText: string);
var
  memo: TfrxMemoView;
begin 
  memo := aReport.FindObject(aMemoName) as TfrxMemoView;
  if memo <> nil then
    memo.Text := aText;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# language you can use the following:

```
report2.RegisterData(dt, "DataTable1");
TextObject t1 = (TextObject)report2.FindObject("Text1");
t1.Text = "I love Kurdistan!";
```